# Submit using a particular button on Return (Enter)?

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, submit

A wizard-type forms has two buttons, Back and Next. Back is on the left, Next is on the right. A minimal example is at http://jsfiddle.net/WSwb7/1/ though submitting a form will not work there.

I thought making the Next button `<input type="submit"` would cause it to be used for submit when the user presses Enter in any form field. However, it appears that when the user hits Enter, the browser uses the first button in the markup, which is the left-hand side Back button (in a `<button>`). Tried FF 30, Chromium 33, IE 11. I wonder if it's described in any standard.

So my problem is how to make a form submit on Enter keypress with the Next button, while having it *to the right* of the Back button. As I use Bootstrap, one would think swapping the buttons in code and positioning in CSS would do without any JS.

How to achieve it? Buttons should be centered in a `<div>` below the form.

(Incidentally, would using right-to-left script not have this kind of problem?:)

Comment: Answers to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102448/) advise placing the copy of the needed button with `visibility:hidden` earlier in the code, but at least IE11 seems to ignore hidden buttons.

Comment: your back button also have "type=submit". remove that and it will work.

Comment: Have you tried 'float : right' on the *next* button. Like this the right button is first in the code.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai nope, it doesn't. Not in Chrome or FF.
@LorenzMeyer I can't seem to get them back to the center of the parent div when I use `float:`

Comment: How you are identifying that submit happened from back or next buttons?

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai submitting from `<button name="wizard_goto_step" value="-1">Back</button>` will result in `wizard_goto_step:-1` in the form's POST data

Answer (score 0):

Write a javascript code for the fields to trigger event to the submit button.

Comment: Javascript is what I want to avoid. Neatly swap two elements with CSS - what could be easier, just I don't seem to be able to achieve it.